# "weird" behavior variable...

Tags: c++, arduino

No more options open other than asking for help here. Whats my problem? First of all I´m a rookie, actually a beginning rookie concerning C++.

In a Arduino project I have this sections:

```
//...

    struct package
    {
      float temperature ;
      float humidity ;
    };
//...
    float remoteTemperature = 0,0;
    float previousRemoteTemperature = 0.1;
    int Temp1 = 0;
    int min_Temp1 = 500;
    int max_Temp1 = -500;
    void printRemoteTemperature()
    {
      String temperature;
      if(remoteTemperature != previousRemoteTemperature)
      {
        if(remoteHumidity == 0.0 && remoteTemperature == 0.0) //We just booted up
        {
          temperature = "---";
        }else
        {
          temperature = String (remoteTemperature,1);
        }
        tft.print(temperature);
        previousRemoteTemperature = remoteTemperature;
        Temp1 = (remoteTemperature);   
        if (Temp1 >= max_Temp1) { max_Temp1 = Temp1; }
        if (Temp1 <= min_Temp1) { min_Temp1 = Temp1; }

        tft.print(min_Temp1);

        tft.print(max_Temp1);
        }
    }
```

Everything (in this case the maximum temp) works fine, except the minimum temperature, which always is 0...

Any help would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: You need to explain your issue more clearly. Are you having issues compiling, or are you having a logical error?

Comment: @Henri isn´t that variable: "int min_Temp1 = 500;"? thanks for your fast response

Comment: sorry, learning to use this properly...

Comment: it compiles just fine! and another identical example works okay for min/max temperatures, here only the max temp works.

Comment: Your title doesn't match the problem in your post.

Comment: sorry, learning to use this properly..

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where the values are actually coming from, but I'll venture a guess.

The `if` statement that's commented with `// We just booted up` leads me to believe that there is a point when the temperature comes in as zero. In that case you set the display to a special value (`"---"`), but the rest of the function is still executed. So your `min_Temp` becomes 0 right at the beginning.
If no temperature value less than zero ever comes in, that will remain the minimum.

Comment: THNX a lot, so a delay before receiving data could be a solution? and removing the special value  ("---") section?

Answer (score 0):

Ihanx to Ionut: I added a line min_Temp1 = 543; before the ,min/max routine, solved the case; a happy man behind the keyboard again.
!